# Get document references from fetched documents (Firestore)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

##### (Firebase Version 9)

I'm trying to get **document references** from the fetched documents of the collection **"products"** with 2 sets of code below but both return **"undefined"**.

**Get single document:**

```js
const docsSnap = await getDoc(
  doc(db, "products/WuAC97j0avTAFNs1kvdf"),
);

console.log(docsSnap.data().ref); // undefined
```

**Get multiple documents:**

```js
const docsSnap = await getDocs(
  collection(db, "products"),
);

console.log(docsSnap.docs[0].data().ref); // undefined
```

Are there any ways to get **document references** from the fetched documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **".data()"** before **".ref"** from both of the code to get **document references**.

**Get single document:**

```js
const docsSnap = await getDoc(
  doc(db, "products/WuAC97j0avTAFNs1kvdf"),
);
                    // Here
console.log(docsSnap.ref); // Tc
```

**Get multiple documents:**

```js
const docsSnap = await getDocs(
  collection(db, "products"),
);
                            // Here
console.log(docsSnap.docs[0].ref); // Tc
```

In addition, you can also get **document IDs** by replacing **".ref"** with **".id"**:

**Get single document:**

```js
const docsSnap = await getDoc(
  doc(db, "products/WuAC97j0avTAFNs1kvdf"),
);
                    // Here
console.log(docsSnap.id); // WuAC97j0avTAFNs1kvdf
```

**Get multiple documents:**

```js
const docsSnap = await getDocs(
  collection(db, "products"),
);
                            // Here
console.log(docsSnap.docs[0].id); // WuAC97j0avTAFNs1kvdf
```